# Can't push my changes to GitHub repository or sync

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

When I try to push my changes to GitHub using VS Code, I get this error:

```
Warning: Failed to watch ref 'k:\******\.git\refs\remotes\origin\main', is most likely packed.
> git config --get commit.template
> git config --get commit.template
> git ls-files --stage -- K:\*****\userChrome.css
> git cat-file -s ec107ff1e90979f0c9ab8b80ac76657a94a0b055
> git show --textconv :userChrome.css
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
```

and it just seems to be trying to sync forever and nothing happens. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What happens if you do it manually from the terminal? `git push`?

Comment: Have you looked into the meaning of ` Failed to watch ref ..., is most likely packed.`? Please explain/show any effort attempted to resolve thus far.

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks so much! Manual push from the terminal just worked!

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the following two commands in your terminal

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

This worked for me.